# How do I get a snowfox in Subnautica?

Tags: subnautica

I've been wondering how to get a Snowfox in Subnautica, can anyone tell me how to get it?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! First, please try to avoid needless extra formatting in your question, that makes it harder to read. Second, if you tell us things you've tried, it will help us help you.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot get a Snowfox in Subnautica. According to the [wiki](https://subnautica-belowzero.fandom.com/wiki/Snowfox):

> The Snowfox is a land vehicle for Below Zero.

Note that [Subnautica](https://store.steampowered.com/app/264710/Subnautica/) and [Subnautica: Below Zero](https://store.steampowered.com/app/848450/Subnautica_Below_Zero/) are different games.